# Utils WriteFile getting error msg

Tags: php, sql, file-io

I'm working on a php/sql program, and I'm trying to print out the result of my query.  It partially works, except for the part where it writes to file (second time).  The error message is

> php fatal error: Call to a member function WriteFile() on a 
>   non-object

This is my code:

```
$result = pg_query ($pg_conn, $qry);
$numrows = pg_num_rows($result);

$mUtils->WriteFile("Query.txt","***********result of qry****************************");
for ($i=0; $i<$numrows; $i++){
       $r = pg_fetch_row($result);
       $name = $r[$i];
       $msUtils->WriteFile($name); //this is where it fails
}
```

Since the first WriteFile works, I think it has to do with $name.  When I look at $r in the debugger, it looks like:

```
[0]=>(string)1
[1]=>(string)something
[2]=>(string)okeyDokey
[3]=>(string)data
[4]=>(string)hmmmm
```

When I look at $name in the debugger it says <(string)1>, which is good.

I have a feeling I need to convert $name somehow that I'm not seeing to use it with WriteFile.

I've looked online but for some reason I'm having trouble finding any examples using WriteFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `$mUtils` and `$msUtils`. It's different objects. And I suppose `$msUtils` even doesn't exist.

Comment: You are a God send.  Thank you very much.  I was focusing on the wrong thing.  You were so quick, the website is making me wait 7 minutes to accept answer!  :)